# images show in chrome but not safari

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I tried to fill rectangles with images. While images appear in Chrome, they do not appear in safari. I do not get any error messages. So I am really confused as to why this is the case, please help me! Alternatively, if you can help with filling rectangles with custom pictures, I'd also happy to hear from you!

```
function initRectElements(svg, data) {
imgUrl = "image/star/5.png";
d3.select(svg).append("defs")
        .append("pattern")
        .attr("id", "rating")
        .attr("width", rectwidth)
        .attr("height", rectheight)
        .append("image")
        .attr("xlink:href", imgUrl)

var sel = d3.select(svg)
        .selectAll('rect.token')
        .data(data);

sel.enter().append('rect')
        .classed('token', true);

sel.exit().remove();

d3.select(svg).selectAll('rect.token')
        .attr('x', function (d){return d
                .x})
        .attr('y', function (d){return d
                .y})
        .attr("width", rectwidth)
        .attr("height", rectheight)
        .attr('fill', "url(#rating)")
```

}

Answer (score 2):

When you are using custom properties with images - Safari interprets images url another way, for example:

[Chrome shows all images, but Safari logs "not allowed to load local resource"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VgKC.png)

Another example:

[Chrome doesn't show all images, but Safari works well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdKqi.png)

The problem is direction, I don't know why but when you using custom properties and set url - safari add one more dot (".") in your url direction.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the things like 
1.-- Add the field !DOCTYPE at the top of your html document or

2.-- if you have image with URL like background-image:url("http://adf.co.us/dm/gs.png");

Then you have to add 
image:url("http://www.adf.co.us/dm/gs.png");

i hope it can be helpful for you.